# Map of promises and conditonnal return

Tags: typescript, dictionary, promise

I am a bit new to promises and I am confused about how to write the correct code.
What the program is doing:

- Get a list of types of items (returned by a promise)
- For all of these item types, try to see if one of the items of this type has a given ID (with another promise)
- If yes, return the type, if not, do nothing.

The code:

```js
  public getItemTypeFromItemId(itemId: string): Promise<ItemTypeName[]> {
    console.log("Searching for ID " + itemId + " in all item types");
    return this.getItemTypes().then(itemtypes => {
      console.log("Found " + itemtypes.length + " item types.")
      let itemtypenames: ItemTypeName[] = [];
      const calls = itemtypes.map(itemtype => {
        console.log("Looking in " + itemtype.name);
        return this.getItemById(itemtype.name, itemId).then(value => {
          if (value !== undefined) {
            console.log("FOUND " + itemId + " within " + itemtype.name);
            // There is an item of this type with this id
            itemtypenames.push(itemtype.name as ItemTypeName);
          }
        });
      });
      return Promise.all(calls).then(() => itemtypenames);
    });
  }
```

Here are the automatic tests, to show you what is expected:

```js
  const PART_ID = "2A1499A5563349DAA1597EFB375FA8F2";
  const CAD_ID = "24FCC02F8BD048C5881E1C63DAFC88BB";

  describe('"getItemTypeFromItemId": get ItemType from item ID', async function () {
    it('Finds the good item type when the ID is present', async function () {
      await itemTypeService.getItemTypeFromItemId(PART_ID).then(itemtypenames => expect(itemtypenames[0]).to.equal("Part"));
      await itemTypeService.getItemTypeFromItemId(CAD_ID).then(itemtypenames => expect(itemtypenames[0]).to.equal("CAD"));
    });

    it('Returns `undefined` if no item with this ID exists', async function () {
      await itemTypeService.getItemTypeFromItemId("").then(itemtypenames => expect(itemtypenames.length).to.equal(0));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Don't think of it as a "conditional return". You get a list of items. Map these to a list of promises with the results of `getItemById`. Await that list to completion (`Promise.all`). You now have a list of ids, some of them undefined. **`.filter` that list to remove the undefined values.**

Comment: Stepping back from that specific issue, though: Why do you have to go hunting through types to find something by ID? Normally I'd expect to be able to get an item by its ID alone, or if the type is necessary, that it would travel with the ID rather than your having to discover it...

Comment: Your return type suggests you want to return the **type** of the item, but the method name suggest you're going to return the item...?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own standalone IDEs to see your issue clearly without introducing problems you're not having.  Right now that snippet seems to require a lot of external code we don't have access to. You should remove any dependency of your example code on private/third-party stuff, so that it's self-contained.  Otherwise any answer you get will be untested and therefore less likely to help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters have noted, it's not exactly clear what the function is meant to achieve. Moreover, it may be simpler to express it using async/await, which is a syntactic sugar around Promises.

**EDIT**: based on your comment, this might be more in line with what you want:

```
public async getItemByIdWithoutItemtype(
  itemId: string,
): Promise<ItemTypeName[]> {
  const itemTypes = await this.getItemTypes();
  const foundItems: ItemTypeName[] = [];
  await Promise.all(
    itemTypes.map(async (itemType) => {
      const foundItem = await this.getItemById(itemtype.name, itemId);
      if (foundItem !== undefined) {
        foundItems.push(itemType.name);
      }
    })
  );
  return foundItems;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I edited the original post to be more precise about what I am looking for. I know look for an array, because I can actually have more than one result. That also removes the need for undefined, if nothing is found, the array will simply be empty. Still, I have the TypeScript error. I will try your approach with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to TypeScript's inference of the return type for Promise.all. TypeScript is interpreting the return type of your function as Promise<ItemTypeName | (ItemTypeName | undefined)[]>, which is not what you intended.

To correctly handle the case where nothing is found and to ensure the return type is Promise, you can use a slightly different approach

```
public getItemByIdWithoutItemtype(itemId: string): Promise<ItemTypeName | undefined> {
return this.getItemTypes().then(itemtypes => {
    const calls = itemtypes.map(itemtype => {
        return this.getItemById(itemtype.name, itemId).then(value => {
            if (value !== undefined) {
                // There is an item of this type with this id
                return itemtype.name as ItemTypeName;
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(calls).then(results => {
        const foundTypes = results.filter(result => result !== undefined) as ItemTypeName[];
        if (foundTypes.length > 0) {
            return foundTypes[0];
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

}